# Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.bottomnav.ClientBottomNav, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The Class `com.example.bottomnav.ClientBottomNav` is present in the project still in the android Manifest it shows the following error-

```
Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.bottomnav.ClientBottomNav, was not found in the project or the libraries  Unresolved class 'ClientBottomNav'
```

As you can see in the image, the project contains all the neccessary classes.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is very probable that the package defined in the manifest doesn't match the one you have in the project, so as you are using just a reference to the class name is not able to resolve it.
Check the tag "package" at the top of your manifest.

You should have something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bottomnav"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Also you might try to set the full path in the activity declaration like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.bottomnav.ClientBottomNav" 
android:label="ClientBottomNav">
```

Also, make sure that you don't declare fragments in the manifest, only activities have to be declared.

Comment: i tried both the methods, neither of them worked for me.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you post in a github gist your whole manifest, and the class declaration of the failing classes? such "class ClientBottomNav extends Activity {}"

Comment: same issue @cdiazmo, could you please check ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683592/missingclass-referenced-class-in-the-manifest-was-not-found-in-the-project-or