# MissingClass : referenced class in the manifest was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-manifest

This is what I got during `cd android && ./gradlew build --warning-mode all` :[image]

Here's my manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.projectTeam.projectName" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="false"
      android:xlargeScreens="false"
      tools:replace="android:smallScreens, android:xlargeScreens"
    />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      >
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So need to make sure, what is the rightest way to make sure that `android:name` in an `<application>` and `<activity>` block is the right one? I checked some similar questions right here, but havent found a key to this issue. App is building fine, but i have in issue with connecting a flipper to it

Answer (score 0):

check this answer for attaching the application class
[Why Do We Extend Application Class In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937490/why-do-we-extend-application-class-in-android)

and also read the setup integration of flipper in android.here is the flipper doc link : https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/android-native/